# encode url in laravel and decode in react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, url, router, encode

I am working on project where backend is in laravel and frontend in react. I want to send some url with some parameters i.e `http:://localhost:3000/reset?email=abc@email.com` to user email and then open that url in frontend and then get email in frontend form url. I am using reach/router. But I don't want this parameter to be visible in browser url bar. Is there any way so I can send encoded url from laravel and then decode and get parameters in react.

Comment: I don't know about react but with the Laravel, you should use the secret token instead of email and then validate this token with users' tokens.

Comment: You can use **Base64 Encode Decode**. Which is compatible on both the side. But directly using `email` is not good. You have to pass a randomly generated token with `reset email link`. Which is the preferred solution.